# I want to download the file from document library in the PDF format using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to download all the files in .pdf format from the document library, it doesn't concern with format which we have uploaded like .xls, .docx etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this link if it helps.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/008eb51a-0c2c-4d65-99a5-8d7634bc1bfa/download-files-from-document-library-in-pdf-using-c?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 1):

Could check the file extension in the code logic like this to download only pdf files:

```
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/devtest"))
        {

            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            ListItemCollection ListItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(ListItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem item in ListItems)
            {
                clientContext.Load(item, i => i.File);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                if (item.File.Name.Split('.')[1].ToLower()=="pdf")
                {
                    var fileRef = item.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
                    var fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\", (string)item.File.Name);
                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                    {
                        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }

            }


        }
```